# Spring Batch issue with sorting Mongo Query

Tags: spring, mongodb, sorting

I am working with Spring Batch to read a Mongo database collection and have run into a problem with sort.  I am user versions:
 3.2.0 of the MongoDriver
 1.8.2.RELEASE of Spring Data
 3.0.6.RELEASE of Spring Batch
 4.2.4.RELEASE of Spring Core

The sort values that Spring does not seem to be accepted by Mongo's driver.  Here is how I configure MongoItemReader:

```
    <bean id="mongodbItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemReader">
    <property name="template" ref="mongoTemplate" />
    <property name="targetType" value="test.model.MongoConverter" />
    <property name="collection" value="report" />
    <property name="query" value="{'id':{$gt:0} }" />
    <property name="sort" >  
        <map>  
            <entry key="_id" value="#{T(org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction).ASC}" />  
        </map>  
    </property>
</bean>
```

The error message I get from this reader is:

```
Exit Status : [org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'bad sort specification' on server 127.0.0.1:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'bad sort specification' on server 127.0.0.1:27017]
```